# How to create clickable points of interest in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to know how i can create something like this (See the picture) in react native, exactly i mean the clickable points of interest.

Is there any component that solves this problem?

Examples:

[image: a busy cat]

Comment: You can create a TouchableOpacity component like a circle shown above and pass func to it.

Comment: How i can do that? is possible to fix the points position with touchableopacity?

Comment: You need to pass position `absolute` and `x` , `y ` to fix the points manually

Comment: do you an example please ?

Comment: sorry my skills in react native is basic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a `Marker` component as shown below. This is just a simple demo, you can modify it as you want

**Marker.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import {TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native'


const Marker = ({onPress, top, left}) => (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress} style={{height: 10, width: 10, borderRadius: 5, backgroundColor: 'red', position: 'absolute', top, left}} />
)

export default Marker
```

**Usage**

```
import Marker from './Marker'

_onPress = () => //...Do the stuff here

render() {
        return (
            <ImageBackground style={{flex: 1}} source={{uri: 'https://s3.envato.com/files/214277896/us-map-html5.png'}} resizeMode={'stretch'}>
                <Marker onPress={this._onPress} top={100} left={200} />
            </ImageBackground>
        )
    }
```

Comment: That will be responsive if i change the background color with the map image?

Comment: The positions will remain fixed based on screen's orientation, the rest can be dynamic.

Comment: so, that will be a problem, because i need it based on the part of image.

Comment: If you wrap an `image` around it, then it will be relative to the `image`. But for that try [ImageBackground](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#background-image-via-nesting)

Comment: So i need to replace the View with ImageBackground right?

Comment: Check the updated code, you just need to fix the positions now, and supply a good image.

Comment: thank you, how i can insert the navigation url, for example when i press in one of the mark i want to redirect to DetailsScreen, thanks again